# insert text field from SQL Server to MYSQL failed

Tags: mysql, sql-server, text, field, data-migration

I'm trying to income data from a SQL Server 2005 table to MySQL 5 table, using SSIS, all columns insert correctly.

Except one column that his type is `TEXT` in SQL Server to MySQL `TEXT` field, and always this column is get NULL !

Comment: what steps are you going through to import the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the text encoding is the same for MySQL as it is for SQL Server.

Comment: i need to change only the char-set of the specific field to char-set latin1 , and its work !

Answer (score 0):

How large is your text field in SQL Server 2005? The basic TEXT field in MySQL has a limit of 65,000 bytes so anything larger than that will be lost and SSIS isn't that hot at letting you know when this is happening. Did you try changing the destination field to MEDIUMTEXT or LONGTEXT?

Also, if that doesn't work you could always try to output the values you are trying to insert into the MySQL 5 table before you actually insert them to see if they are being padded with spaces or something else odd is happening.